# How to generate list of named classes and object property names in a given ontology using java & jena

Tags: java, jena, owl

Here is the owl ontology that represents information on artists, musicians and musical hits

```xml
<rdf:RDF xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt"/>
  <!-- 
       ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       //
       // Object Properties
       //
       ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  -->
  <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#hasComposed -->
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#hasComposed">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#hasCreated"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>

  <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#hasCreated -->
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#hasCreated"/>

  <!-- 
       ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       //
       // Classes
       //
       ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  -->

  <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#ArtisticWork -->
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#ArtisticWork"/>

  <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#Composition -->
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#Composition">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#ArtisticWork"/>
  </owl:Class>

  <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#MusicalHit -->
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#MusicalHit">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#Composition"/>
  </owl:Class>

  <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#Person -->
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#Person"/>

  <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#PopularMusician -->
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#PopularMusician">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#hasCreated"/>
        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#MusicalHit"/>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#Person"/>
  </owl:Class>

  <!-- 
       ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       //
       // Individuals
       //
       ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  -->

  <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#imagine -->
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#imagine">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#MusicalHit"/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>

  <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#jealousGuy -->
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#jealousGuy">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#MusicalHit"/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>

  <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#lennon -->
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#lennon">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#Person"/>
    <hasComposed rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#imagine"/>
    <hasComposed rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/MyArt#jealousGuy"/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>

</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the ontology into an [`OntModel`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html), and then you can use [`OntModel#listObjectProperties`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#listObjectProperties%28%29) and [`OntModel#listClasses`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#listClasses%28%29) to get object properties and classes.  You will need to filter out non-named classes from the latter, though, since `listClasses` returns an iterator over all the classes, not just named classes.  For that filtering, it looks like you could use various `OntClass#isXXX` methods, e.g., [`OntClass#isComplementClass`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html#isComplementClass%28%29) to check whether classes are named classes, or non-named class expressions.

If you're new to Jena, the [Apache Jena](http://jena.apache.org/) page has lots of resources and documentation to get you started.